# How to solve Javascript escape when escape sequence is not encoded properly

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

I have a text string that includes an escape sequence like `\u00f1`. When I ingest in JS and try to append the string to a div, it's literally rendering `\u00f1` rather than `ñ`.

I've tried `en/decodeURIComponent` and `un/escape()` to no avail.

Any tricks on how to get the escape sequence rendering the correct `UTF-8` character in JS?

**P.S.** The page is already encoded in `UTF-8`

Comment: Can you show us a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

The only sane solution is to make sure HTML is properly encoded. Trying to "decode" content may easily bring cross-site-scripting (XSS) issues (incomplete attempt to fix it is likely reason why you see over-encoded text).

Otherwise you can try to decode it several times (for good measure) by using innerHTML and content properties...